# How to write LINQ query for fetching the specific records and generating new result at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have to update one field in the row of the table after fetching two records from the same row. As an easiest practice I have fetched two records individually, created a new value and then updating that particular property through Entity framework. I think there is a better way to do the same thing with less code. If any body can suggest please.

```
if (objModel.amountpaid==0)
                {
                    using (estatebranchEntities db=new estatebranchEntities())
                    {
                        int rentVar = Convert.ToInt32(db.PropertyDetails.Where(m => m.propertyid == objVM.propertyid).Select(m => m.rent).SingleOrDefault());
                        int balanceVar = Convert.ToInt32(db.PropertyDetails.Where(m => m.propertyid == objVM.propertyid).Select(m => m.balance).SingleOrDefault());
                        int balanceUpdateVar = (rentVar + balanceVar);
                        var propInfo = new PropertyDetail() { balance = balanceUpdateVar };
                        //var result = (from a in db.PropertyDetails
                        //              where a.propertyid == objVM.propertyid
                        //              select new PropertyDetail
                        //              {
                        //                  rent = a.rent,
                        //                  balance = a.balance
                        //              }).ToList();

                        db.PropertyDetails.Attach(propInfo);
                        db.Entry(propInfo).Property(z => z.balance).IsModified = true;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think you can do.

Fetch the data once and update once.

```
using (estatebranchEntities db=new estatebranchEntities())
{
    var propDetails = db.PropertyDetails.FirstOrDefault(m => m.propertyid == objVM.propertyid);
    if (propDetails != null)
    {
        int rentVar = Convert.ToInt32(propDetails.rent);
        int balanceVar  = Convert.ToInt32(propDetails.balance);
        int balanceUpdateVar = rentVar + balanceVar;
        //now do the update
        propDetails.balance = balanceUpdateVar;
        db.Entry(proDetails).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

if you need to use the `rentVar`,`balanceVar` or the `balanceUpdateVar`, outside of the using statement then declare them outside it.